# Can a python class have multiple grandparents?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, python-class

So I just come across a function called `super()` that will call every parent's version of the function, but when I tried several different things there are things that i didn't quite understand. Here, suppose I have 2 classes `Human` and `Ghost`

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name, "is a human")

class Ghost:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name, "is a ghost")
```

and I have 3 sub classes with `Human` and `Ghost` as their parent

```
# Child of Human class
class Run(Human):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name, "can run")
        super().__init__(name)

# Child of Human class
class Whisper(Human):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name, "can whisper")
        super().__init__(name)

# Child of Ghost class
class Fly(Ghost):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name, "can fly")
        super().__init__(name)
```

My problem are

1. If I create a `Robot` class that has `Run` and `Whisper` classes as its parent

```
class Robot(Run, Whisper):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am Robot")
        super().__init__('Robot')
```

and when i create `r` as `Robot` class, and run the code the result would be like this

```
>>> r = Robot()
I am Robot
Robot can run
Robot can whisper
Robot is a human
```

2. And my second problem was, if I create a `Robot` class with `Run` and `Fly` as its parent

```
class Robot(Run, Fly):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am Robot")
        super().__init__('Robot')
```

and create `r` as `Robot` class, run the code i get this result

```
>>> r = Robot()
I am Robot
Robot can run
Robot is a human
```

My Question is

1. Why in the first number, in the `Human` class, `print(name, "is a human")` only run once not twice ? While both of the class `Run` and `Whisper` has `super()` function inside of them
2. Why in the second number, the `Run` and `Human` classes was successfully called while the `Fly` and `Ghost` classes is not being called ?
3. Is there a way to use multiple different grandparents in a single class ?

Comment: You are severely misunderstanding `super()` - it calls *one* parent's implementation of the method, for this to work in the presence of multiple inheritance, EVERY class must use `super()`, even the base classes.

Comment: Several misconceptions: `super` is a type, not a function. It does not call *every* parent's version; it provides a reference to the *next* version of an attribute in the method resolution order. Only when each method uses `super` to continue the "chain" do classes work together to ensure that every method is called.

Comment: Please read https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/.

Comment: @chepner has a good explanation, I think all your questions are covered there.

Comment: Thank you @chepner and @jasonharper, I just understand that, but it makes me think is it practical to use `super` in this "chain" situation ?

Comment: Because @chepner said that to continue the "chain" each method must uses `super` and i just tried that, but if i put super on all the classes it returns an error because the next "chain" is not found, and as a programmer to design such thing would be hard wouldn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it *is* (relatively) hard to properly design a class hierarchy involving multiple inheritance. Again, read the link above for advice on how to do that. (There are also numerous questions on Stack Overflow that provide concrete examples of using `super` according to the advice in that link.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article about [method resolution order](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html):

> In languages that use **multiple inheritance**, the order in which base
> classes are searched when looking for a method is often called the
> Method Resolution Order, or MRO. (**In Python this also applies to other
> attributes**.)

Classic classes used a simple MRO scheme: when looking up a method, base classes were searched using a simple depth-first left-to-right scheme. The first matching object found during this search would be returned.
[Read more here](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html)